# How do I get previous directories and folders using PuTTY?

Tags: file, text, directory, putty

I created a directory root/, folder /temp and change it with emacs folder, and then add a file quote_dora. I want to add a text file to quote_dora.

Comment: Please add screen shot if possible to easily understand what you are trying to achieve OR describe in a bit more detail. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out already.
Runs emacs quote_dora
write text on quote_dora file
ctl-x and ctl-c to save and exist.